# Let $g_n^k=p_{n+k}-p_n$, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime. Does there exist $g_{k+1}^1=2$ such that $g_1^k,g_2^k,\ldots$ is a "Gilbreath sequence?"

Tags: prime-numbers, recurrence-relations, twin-primes, prime-gaps

Call $(S_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ a Gilbreath sequence if $1=\lvert S_2-S_1\rvert=\lvert \lvert S_3-S_2\rvert-\lvert S_2-S_1\rvert\rvert=\cdots$, i.e., if the sequence can be substituted for the primes in [Gilbreath's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbreath%27s_conjecture).

Let $g_n^k=p_{n+k}-p_n$, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime. Do there exist twin primes $p_{k+1},\ p_{k+2}$ such that $g_1^k,g_2^k,\ldots$ is a Gilbreath sequence? That there exists some such $k$ is a generalization of Gilbreath's conjecture, since it is the case $k=1$.

To give a simple example, it appears that we can take $k=2$, which has the sequence of gaps $5-2=3,\ 7-3=4,\ 11-5=6,\ 13-7=6,17-11=6,\ 19-13=6,\ldots,$
which have absolute differences $1,2,0,0,0,\ldots$

Comment: Do you mean for which k, the extended Gilbreath secquence is a normal Gilbreath sequence too after somewhere?

Comment: I think so? I believe my definitions are consistent with what I intended. The idea is to write out the sequence of primes, then take the differences between the terms whose indices differ by some constant $k$, and finally, put those in place of the primes in Gilbreath's conjecture, which is why $g_2^k-g_1^k=(p_{k+2}-p_2)-(p_{k+1}-p_1)=g_{n+1}^1-1=1$. I'm not certain if this answers your question, as I haven't defined anything that extends what I've defined as a Gilbreath sequence.

Comment: I think your indexes do not represent what you want. If have understood your question correctly, you mean that for example for $k=2$ you want to prove why $g_n^2$ and $|g_{n+1}^2-g_n^2|=||p_{n+3}-p_{n+2}|-|p_{n+2}-p_{n+1}||$ and so on make Gilbreath sequence.

Comment: No, I want to see if, for example, $g_1^2,g_2^2,\ldots=3,4,6,6,6,6,\ldots$ is a Gilbreath sequence. The sequence formed by certain $k$ and $n=1,2,\ldots$ is what's conjectured to be a Gilbreath sequence.

Comment: @Arashium If my indices are messed up then perhaps you can fix them. The idea is that for twin primes like $17$ and $19$, the differences $17-2=15$ and $19-3=16$ always differ by $1$, so $15,16,\ldots$ might be used in place of the primes.

Comment: May I know whether it is your own question or you found this question somewhere?

Comment: @Arashium I have not found it anywhere. My thinking was that it might be between Vinogradov and Goldbach in difficulty, and possibly approachable to someone familiar with the circle method. At the very least it can't be harder than Goldbach's conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

Till now, I cannot tell you for which $k$ the sequence is Gilbreath. But at least I can tell you for which $k$ it is not Gilbreath.

It was a hard attempt for my laptop CPU to test 50000 sequences for k from 1 to 100 which took 231.3s time.

I obtained the following results:

```
k=1
Gilbreath passed 49999 tests successfully
k=2
Gilbreath passed 49998 tests successfully
k=3
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=4
Gilbreath passed 49996 tests successfully
k=5
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=6
Gilbreath passed 49994 tests successfully
k=7
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=8
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=9
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=10
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=11
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=12
Gilbreath passed 49988 tests successfully
k=13
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=14
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=15
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=16
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=17
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=18
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=19
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=20
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=21
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=22
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=23
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=24
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=25
Gilbreath rejected at n=5
k=26
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=27
Gilbreath rejected at n=3
k=28
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=29
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=30
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=31
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=32
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=33
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=34
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=35
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=36
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=37
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=38
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=39
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=40
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=41
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=42
Gilbreath rejected at n=4
k=43
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=44
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=45
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=46
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=47
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=48
Gilbreath rejected at n=5
k=49
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=50
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=51
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=52
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=53
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=54
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=55
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=56
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=57
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=58
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=59
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=60
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=61
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=62
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=63
Gilbreath rejected at n=3
k=64
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=65
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=66
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=67
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=68
Gilbreath passed 49932 tests successfully
k=69
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=70
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=71
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=72
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=73
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=74
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=75
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=76
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=77
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=78
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=79
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=80
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=81
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=82
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=83
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=84
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=85
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=86
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=87
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=88
Gilbreath rejected at n=3
k=89
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=90
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=91
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=92
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=93
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=94
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=95
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=96
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=97
Gilbreath rejected at n=2
k=98
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
k=99
Gilbreath rejected at n=1
```

Running the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> num_vec;

// Generating a huge list of prime numbers 
void fill_prime(num_vec &primes, int N)
{   // N is to be a huge number
    primes.reserve(N);
    primes.push_back(2); // the only even number
    int found_counter=1;
    int prime_target=3;

    while(found_counter<N)
    {   // find more primes
        bool rejected=false;
        for(int k=0;k<found_counter && primes[k]*primes[k]<=prime_target && !rejected;k++)
        {
            if(prime_target%primes[k]==0) // dividable by previous prime numbers
                rejected=true;
        }
        if(!rejected) // is prime
        {
            primes.push_back(prime_target);  // add to the list of primes
            found_counter++;
        }
        prime_target+=2; // next odd number
    }
}

num_vec Gilbreath(const num_vec &numbers,const int k)
{
    num_vec results;
    const int gilbsize=numbers.size()-k;
    if(gilbsize<=0)
        return results;
    results.reserve(gilbsize);
    for(int n=0;n<gilbsize;n++)
        results.push_back(abs(numbers[n]-numbers[n+k]));
    return results;
}

void check_Gilbreath(const num_vec &numbers)
{
    num_vec g(numbers);
    int n=0;
    while(g.size()>1)
    {
        g=Gilbreath(g,1);
        n++;
        if(g[0]!=1)
        {
            std::cout<<"Gilbreath rejected at n="<<n<<std::endl;
            return ;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Gilbreath passed "<<numbers.size()<<" tests successfully"<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int N_prime=50000;
    const int k=2;
    num_vec primes;
    fill_prime(primes,N_prime);
    for(int k=1;k<100;k++)
    {
        std::cout<<"k="<<k<<std::endl;
        num_vec gilbk=Gilbreath(primes,k);
        check_Gilbreath(gilbk); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you believe this code needs an improvement, you may alter it on [github](https://github.com/arashium/math/blob/master/2015-02-05/gilbreath.cpp).

I hope some one can give you a better idea.